# Can I change table structure in a transaction and then roll it back if there is an error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transaction, rollback

I have some `ALTER TABLE` statements that I am running. Not all of them work (they are the result of running SQL Data Compare) and I want to group them in some transactions and roll back the statements if something goes wrong.

Is this possible, or is it only data that can be rolled back?

Comment: Are you talking about Redgate SQL Compare? One of the synchronization options there is to use transactions IIRC so you could look at the generated script there to see some boiler plate code for this.

Comment: Yes I am. I shall take a look at that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```sql
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
      BEGIN TRY
        ALTER TABLE1...
        ALTER TABLE2...
        -- Additional data/structural changes
        COMMIT
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
         ROLLBACK;
         THROW; -- Only if you want reraise an exception (to determine the reason of the exception)
      END CATCH
```

Comment: Would `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and a final `COMMIT TRAN` negate the need for the `TRY` blocks?

Comment: @LukePuplett ["Compile errors, such as syntax errors, are not affected by SET XACT_ABORT."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, this is possible.

Most DDL statements can be rolled back in SQL Server (There are a few exceptions such as `CREATE DATABASE`)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible to use many `ALTER TABLE` statements in one transaction with `ROLLBACK` and `COMMIT`.

Here is a scaffold for your script (following [MS guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) with improvements):

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
    -- place your script in this TRY block

    -- your DDL instructions:
    ALTER TABLE1...
    ALTER TABLE2...
    -- data modifications:
    EXEC('
        UPDATE A
        SET    c1 = 23,
               c2 = ''ZZXX'';
    ');
    -- another DDL instruction:
    ALTER TABLE2...

    -- end of your script
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;


    -- If you want reraise an exception (to determine the reason of the exception)
    -- just uncomment block with appropriate version:

    -- SQL SERVER >= 2012
    /*
    THROW;
    */

    -- SQL SERVER < 2012 (tested against 2008 R2)
    /*
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (
        @ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
        @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
        @ErrorState -- State.
    );
    */
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Be careful, `THROW` works only for SQL SERVER version >= 2012. Here you could convert a version from *semver* to *year notation*: http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.ru (do not aware of `.ru` domain, there is an English version)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into transactions and exception handling in T-SQL. Check out the last two examples on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx